# Line integral doesn't compute

Tags: sympy

I'm asked to compute a line integral where

```py
import sympy as sp 
import sympy.vector as sv 

C = sv.CoordSys3D("")
x, y, z = C.base_scalars()
i, j, k = C.base_vectors()

Ffield = sp.atan(x*y)*i + sp.acos(y*z)*j + sp.asin(x*z)*k
Gfield = x*y*z*i + sp.sqrt(x*y*z)*j
Afield = sv.gradient(Ffield.dot(Gfield))
Tpath = sv.ParametricRegion( (t,sp.exp(t),sp.ln(t)), (t,1,5) )
```

Now `sv.vector_integrate(Afield,Tpath)` never ends and I'm not sure why. The integrand looks complicated, but I think this is the method I should use.

Comment: Most integrals cannot be computed analytically. It looks like `integrate` is trying hard to do it but I doubt that this integral has a reasonable analytic result. Better to compute it numerically.

Comment: Could you point me to a method to integrate numerically?